# How to add WCF service reference in Xamarin Forms .netstandard?

Tags: wcf, xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I've created a Xamarin Forms project with .netstandard and trying to add the WCF service reference as the connected service using Visual Studio 2017. There is an option in the connected service for adding WCF service reference. When I add the service reference, a dialog box opens and after few seconds an error comes as it is not able to build the solution. But when I try to build the solution, it builds but the reference don't add. How can I add the WCF service reference in .netstandard project with Xamarin Forms.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by uncheck the option for Reuse the types in referenced assemblies in Data Type Options